# Parsing XML Recieved from Curl for Specific Values

Tags: xml, curl, xml-parsing

I'm trying to filter this code for the data between `<cookie>` & `</cookie>` and the data between `account-id="` & `"` (the trailing quote)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
 <status code="ok"/>
 <common locale="en" time-zone-id="85">
  <cookie>na3breezfxm5hk6co2kfzuxq</cookie>
  <date>2012-11-11T16:26:52.713+00:00</date>
  <host>http://meet97263421.adobeconnect.com</host>
  <local-host>pacna3app09</local-host>
  <admin-host>na3cps.adobeconnect.com</admin-host>
  <url>/api/xml?action=common-info</url>
  <version>8.2.2.0</version>
  <tos-version>7.5</tos-version>
  <product-notification>true</product-notification>
  <account account-id="1013353222"/>
  <user-agent>curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5</user-agent>
 </common>
</results>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

This is the curl command I run to return the above xml.

```
curl -s http://meet97263421.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=common-info
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, regexes (and therefore `grep`) [aren't well-suited to parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/900873), but if you can guarantee the input is well-formatted and consistent you can do this most easily with `grep`'s perl-style regexes (on systems whose grep has them):

```sh
grep -oP '(?<=<cookie>).*?(?=</cookie>)'
grep -oP '(?<=account-id=").*?(?=")'
```

If you want them in the same command, you can separate them with a `|`, but then you have to tell which matches which.

```sh
grep -oP '(?<=<cookie>).*?(?=</cookie>)|(?<=account-id=").*?(?=")'
```

Comment: your `grep` commands work great! How would I go about using the -e command. I've edited the question with my `curl` input.

Comment: it says `grep: the -P option only supports a single pattern`

Comment: Interesting. You can use alternation (`|`) instead, I've tested this one.

Comment: Once in a while I find these answers and I go, I'm so glad I am not still in the 90s and 2000s.

Answer (score 5):

As stated by @Kevin regular expressions are ill-suited to parsing XML.

A better approach is to use the **xmllint** program which apply an xpath expression as follows:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "string(/results/common/cookie)" data.xml
na3breezfxm5hk6co2kfzuxq

$ xmllint --xpath "string(/results/common/account/@account-id)" data.xml
1013353222
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these XPath expressions

```
/results/common/cookie

/results/common/account/@account-id
```

with a command line XPath interpreter